# Bootstraps side navigation bar Code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is the side navigation for the various sections on the bootstraps website (CSS, JavaScript, Components) available? The nav bar that shows you what part of the page you are on as you scroll down.

As in, does bootstraps provide the code for this feature? Or is it their own?

Heres a screen shot of the nav bar i am talking about!

[image]